# Error #1067 when I am using a dynamic Text field

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{
    public class supportForce extends MovieClip
    {
        var NeonCD:int = 0;
        public function supportForce()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, general);
        }
        private function general(event:Event)
        {
            if (NeonCD > 0)
            {
                NeonCD -=  1;
            }
            status_text = NeonCD;
        }
    }
}
```

So this is a pretty simple question that I really need to be answered as I am using it a lot. There is a dynamic text field called status_text. It is supposed to constantly update the value of a variable, NeonCD. It gives Error #1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.text:TextField. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is declaration of "status_text"? What line of code generates error?

Comment: Do you have to declare it? Sorry I don't know. I just drew it using the Text Tool on the stage and gave it and instance name "status_text".

Comment: I feel like a magician, but could you try to write "status_text.text = NeonCD.toString();" instead of current "status_text = NeonCD;"?

Comment: Sorry, but it gives the same error though I replaced it with  "status_text.text = NeonCD.toString();".

Comment: I don't understand. You wrote that my code gives same error, but accept answer with SAME code, that I represented before =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

status-text type of TextField and NeonCD is type of int... you need change text with textfield object's text property like this -
 `status_text.text` 
which changes textfields text and need type of String and you can cast int into String like this `NeonCD.toString();`

`status_text.text`  = `NeonCD.toString();`